# Setw() in C++ isn't responding as I expected

Tags: c++, formatting, setw

So the below code works fine, with one exception:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int value1, value2, value3, value4;
    float calcMean,calcStDev;


    // Input values from keyboard
        // prompt user for input
    cout << "Enter 1st value. " << endl;
    cin >> value1;
    cout << "Enter 2nd value. " << endl;
    cin >> value2;
    cout << "Enter 3rd value. " << endl;
    cin >> value3;
    cout << "Enter 4th value. " << endl;
    cin >> value4;

    // Calculate the mean, mean = (value1 + value2 + value3 + value4)/4.0
    calcMean = (value1 + value2 + value3 + value4) / 4.0;

    // Calculate the standard deviation, standard deviation = squareroot((sum((input value-mean)*(input value-mean)))/number of input value - 1)
    calcStDev = sqrt((pow((value1 - calcMean),2) + pow((value2 - calcMean),2) + pow((value3 - calcMean),2) + pow((value4 - calcMean),2))/(4-1));
        // Output display
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;
    cout << "Mean of the four values:               " << setw(10) << calcMean << endl;
    cout << "Standard deviation of the four values: " << setw(10) << calcStDev << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The output doesn't seem to be responding to the setw() like I expected (I wanted the number 18.50 to be directly over 19.64, one on top of the other).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?:

```
Enter 1st value.
2
Enter 2nd value.
36
Enter 3rd value.
35
Enter 4th value.
1

Mean of the four values:                                     18.50
Standard deviation of the four values:      19.64
```

Comment: Here it works, both with g++ 4.8.1 and clang 3.4.

Comment: Please document what text editor you used, we'll want to avoid such an incredibly evil one.

Comment: @Hans Passant For example MS VS code editor.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that string literal `"Mean of the four values:               "` contains embedded tab characters. It is possible that to insert spaces you pressed the TAB key instead of SPACEBAR key.